# Views Sort Criteria: Contextual Filter Multiple Value Order

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that pulls in a collection of nodes via node id.  I'm using the Node:Nid filter, and have it set to allow multiple inputs separated by the '+' sign. (443+112+2060...)  This part works beautifully.

I was wondering if I could sort the view by the order of the nids?  I thought it might do this by default if I remove all sort criteria, but no joy. I'm looking and I don't see a way to sort the view by this data.

Any advice you might be able to give me would be greatly appreciated.

Drupal 7. Views 7.x-3.x-dev.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess some other people had the same idea I had.

The [Views Arguments Extras](http://drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras) module handles my situation perfectly. I used the version for 7 (duh :) ), but there is a drupal 6 version as well.

Comment: Use dev-version. Production version doesn't work for me.